# Ramification Groups without valuations

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $L,K$ be number fields, with $L/K$ a Galois extension, and $Q$ a prime ideal in $L$. Let $E$ be the inertia group, and $H=\{\sigma \in Gal(L/K) : \sigma(x) \equiv x \pmod {Q^2}\,\forall x\in O_L\}$. I want to prove:

(a) For $p\in Q-Q^2$, for each $\sigma \in H$ there is $\alpha_\sigma \in O_L$ such that $\sigma(p)\equiv \alpha_\sigma p \pmod{Q^2}$

(b) For $\sigma, \tau \in H$, $\alpha_{\sigma\tau}\equiv \alpha_\sigma \alpha_\tau \pmod {Q^2}$

I did the first one as follows: write $(p)=QI$. Then from the Chinese remainder theorem there is $a$ s.t. $a\equiv\sigma(p) \pmod {Q^2}$, $a \equiv 0 \pmod I$.
It is also known that $Q/Q^2$ is isomorphic to $O_L/Q$, and in particular there is $z\in Q$ s.t. $z\equiv 1\pmod {Q^2}$. Then $za=up$ for some $u\in O_L$, and we can take $\alpha_\sigma=u$.
I don't know how to solve $(b)$. I understand you can use valuations, but I rather avoid it.

Comment: I started editing your post (cleaning up TeX, spacing and such). Hopefully what I did looks ok to you!? But, it seems to me that you are using $I$ with two different meanings? First to denote the inertia group, then some other ideal. Those are incompatible. Can you clarify, please.

Comment: Another thing I find slightly odd. The notation $\alpha_\sigma$ suggests that may be $\alpha_\sigma$ is supposed to be independent from $p$. In other words, may be the same 
$\alpha_\sigma$ should work for all $p\in Q\setminus Q^2$? Then $(b)$ gives a homomorphism from $H$ to a structure intrinsic to $O_L$. Something similar often happens when we study quotients of two higher ramification groups, so may be there is something to my suspicion. Can you check such details?

Comment: You are correct about the double use of I, thanks. About your second comment, I don't know. But thisdoes imply there is a homomorphism from the inertia group to (O_L/Q)^* with kernel H.